# Get javascript array first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How can I get the first element of an array in javascript by a means other than `array[0]`?

I do not know why, but for some reason the array that gets passed into the method has its first, and only, element at index 5, not 0.

**Edit** - Here is my attempt at providing a minimal reproducible example.

```
      // Initialize database connection string datatable editor
  editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
    table: "#remoteSqlDatabaseTable",
    ajax: $("#UpdateIntegrationRemoteSqlDatabaseAction").val(),
    fields: [
      { label: 'Reference Name', name: 'Name' },
      { label: 'IP Address or Host', name: 'IpAddress' },
      { label: 'Port', name: 'Port' },
      { label: 'Username', name: 'UserCredential' },
      { label: 'Password', name: 'PasswordCredential', def: '' },
      { name: 'button' }
    ]
  });

  editor
    .on('open', function (e, type) {
      if (type === 'inline') {
        // Listen for a tab key event when inline editing
        $(document).on('keydown.editor', function (e) {
          if (e.keyCode === 9 || e.keyCode === 13) {
            editor.blur();
          }
        });
      }
      if (editor.s.includeFields[0] === 'PasswordCredential') {
        editor.field(editor.s.includeFields[0]).val('');
      }
    })
    .on('close', function () {
      $(document).off('keydown.editor');
    })
    .on('preSubmit', function (e, edit) {
      if (edit.data[1].PasswordCredential !== undefined) {
        var value = edit.data[1].PasswordCredential;
        // check for null or whitespace
        if (typeof value === 'undefined' || value == null || value.replace(/\s/g, '').length < 1) {
          editor.close();
          return false;
        }
      }
    });


  // Configure inline editing columns
  $('#remoteSqlDatabaseTable').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:last-child)', function (e) {
    editor.inline(this, {
      submitOnBlur: true
    });
  });

  // Reload data on edit to handle reordering
  //editor.on("submitSuccess", function () {
  //  var table = $('#databaseConnectionTable').DataTable();
  //  console.log('submitSuccess');
  //  table.ajax.reload(function () {
  //    initTableStyling();
  //  });
  //})

  // Initialize datatable
  var table = $('#remoteSqlDatabaseTable').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: false,
    ajax: $("#GetIntegrationRemoteSqlDatabasesAction").val(),
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    columns: [
      { data: 'Name' },
      { data: 'IpAddress' },
      { data: 'Port' },
      { data: 'UserCredential' },
      { data: 'PasswordCredential' },
      { data: null }
    ],
    select: false,
    responsive: false,
    buttons: [],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        targets: -1,
        data: null,
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
          return '<button class="btn red" type="button">Delete</button>';
        }
      }
    ],
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
      //initTableStyling();
    }
  });
```

Like i said, i am not sure exactly where the problem is coming from. The method that is breaking is the editor.on('presubmit'), where it check if(edit.data[1] . edit.data[1] is the object that only has a 5th element.

this is everything relating to the table whos editing is the problem.

Comment: If the element is at 5, have you tried `array[5]`?

Comment: Do you want to get the first *non empty* element in the array?

Comment: You can create an array of 6 empty "slots" with `new Array(6)`, then assign only to the `5`th slot. Something like `arr.find(Boolean)` would give the first truth-y value, but you should find out *why* this is happening.

Comment: I have and it works but I need a better solution than that. This method used to work with the first element being at 0. Now, for no reason, the first element is at 5. So doing that could lead to the same problem in the future when the first element arbitrarily decides to be at index 3.

Comment: @haim770 yes, i'd like to get the first anything in the array. slots 0-4 dont even exist. its not like they're there but empty. they dont exist at all. so i need the first slot that exists

Comment: Or `find(x => x !== null && x !== undefined)` to make it stop on the first non-null

Comment: If your array is broken, why don't fix it at the source?

Comment: it was my understanding that javascript cant use linq queries

Comment: @Ilan_Schindler, This is not LINQ but standard Array methods in Javascript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: @Taplar null is not the same thing as empty

Comment: the method that gets called is an event listener, so the data gets passed through a bunch of different levels before reaching this one. i tried to backtrack and find where the problem was coming from but couldnt

Comment: Ah, if it is **empty** it would be `!== undefined` instead of null

Comment: @Taplar undefined is also not the same as empty! Empty array slots aren't actually included in map, filter, etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `var x = []; x[5] = 'wee'; x.find(it => it !== undefined);`

Comment: @Taplar yes, `!== null` and `!== undefined` will both work, but if you add a `console.log` in your callback you'll see it's because the empty values *aren't processed at all*, whereas if you did e.g. `x[1] = undefined` that (undefined) value *would* be processed.

Comment: upon further inspection, the array is being recognized as an "object", not an array. so the find method returns an error because object.find doesnt exist

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: `var x = []; x[5] = 'wee'; x.find((it, index) => { console.log(it, index); return it !== undefined; });` logs `undefined` for me for indexes 0-4 in firefox.  That doesn't seem to mach what you are saying. @jonrsharpe  Edit: The same behavior is logged in Chrome

Comment: @Taplar oh interesting; for `.find` it does, for e.g. `.filter` it doesn't. Per MDN [*"`callback` is invoked for every index of the array, not just those with assigned values."*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I guess you have to check for each array method whether they include unassigned indices. But all of this is redundant if the OP doesn't have an array.

Comment: I'm guessing if you changed `IpAddress` it would come back as element 2? Or is it just a coincidence that `PasswordCredential` is the 5th column (4th if counting via 0). My answer will pull that value out of the object.

Comment: no matter which element is edited, its the 5th element. there is no correlation between its place in the table and the data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Updated answer, this works with objects. It isn't a pretty as `find` `filter` answers but it simply works.

Loop through the object and set a value.
Since there is only one element, it will set the variable without overwriting anything.

```js
testArray = {"5" : "test"};
var val = "";
for(key in testArray){val = testArray[key];}
console.log(val);
```

Comment: That's only true if you want a string, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is true, the OP never really states what the contents of the element are, just how to get that element. So this is a clean cross browser solution.

Comment: ...for strings. It's worth at least mentioning that constraint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my answer since the OP said it was an object not an array.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
let [first_element] = your_array
```

Comment: That would be the same as accessing `your_array[0]`.

Comment: Then do this `array.find(Boolean)`

Comment: Yes, I suggested as much in the comments above, I'm commenting on the actual content of your answer.